# How to enable text wrapping in CheckBox

Tags: xml, wpf, checkbox, word-wrap, stackpanel

How I can wrap text in CheckBox? The text is a bit longer than width of page, but I cannot shorten it. CheckBox doesnt have TextWrapping attribute. ;(
Also I tried to set Width="460", Width="*", but I didnt succeed.

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox Content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit." />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
<CheckBox>
    <TextBlock Text="Test Text" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why this worked.

Comment: CheckBox doesn’t have" Wrap"  for "Content" Property as "Content" is an object type. Solution: use custom Content.